# Autofac OwnedInstances and ASP.NET Web API's InstancePerApiRequest support

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, autofac

For my ASP.NET Web API project, I have the following set up which uses Autofac as the IoC container:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpConfiguration config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;

    config.DependencyResolver = 
        new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(
            RegisterServices(new ContainerBuilder()));

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultRoute", "api/{controller}");
}

private static IContainer RegisterServices(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    builder.RegisterType<ConfContext>().InstancePerApiRequest();

    return builder.Build();
}
```

And I have the following message handler which retrieves the `ConfContext` instance just for fun:

```
public class MyHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        ConfContext ctx = (ConfContext)request.GetDependencyScope().GetService(typeof(ConfContext));
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

As my message handler will be called before the controller is constructed, I should get the same `ConfContext` instance at the controller. However, I want to get separate instances if I try to retrieve a `ConfContext` as `Func<Owned<ConfContext>>` but I am getting the same instance. If I remove the `InstancePerApiRequest` registration, I will lose the Per API request support on cases where I want to just retrieve the `ConfContext` as it is.

Is there any way to support both cases here?

**Edit**

Sample application is here: https://github.com/tugberkugurlu/EntityFrameworkSamples/tree/master/EFConcurrentAsyncSample/EFConcurrentAsyncSample.Api

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Autofac 3.0 I added support for applying multiple tags to a lifetime scope. You can use this to apply tags for the API request and Owned instance lifetime scopes.

The tag for Web API lifetime scopes is exposed via the `AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver.ApiRequestTag` property, and `Owned<T>` lifetime scopes are tagged with their entry point `new TypedService(typeof(T))`.

Put that together into a handy registration extension method and you get the code below.

```
public static class RegistrationExtensions
{
    public static IRegistrationBuilder<TLimit, TActivatorData, TStyle>
        InstancePerApiRequestOrOwned<TLimit, TActivatorData, TStyle>(
            this IRegistrationBuilder<TLimit, TActivatorData, TStyle> registration)
    {
        if (registration == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("registration");

        var tags = new object[] {AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver.ApiRequestTag, new TypedService(typeof(TLimit))};

        return registration.InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope(tags);
    }
}
```

Now you can use the extension method when registering your types and all is well.

```
builder.RegisterType<ConfContext>().InstancePerApiRequestOrOwned();
```

I sent you a pull request demonstrating this code.

https://github.com/tugberkugurlu/EntityFrameworkSamples/pull/1